# My Code won't stop printing in a loop

Tags: java, loops

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Bank
{
    double balance = 0;
    double amount = 0;

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int userChoice;
    BankAccount account1 = new BankAccount();
    boolean quit = false;
    {
        do {
            System.out.println("Your Choice: ");
            System.out.println("For Deposit type 1");
            System.out.println("For Withdraw type 2");
            System.out.println("For Check Balance type 3");
            System.out.println("Type 0 to quit");
            userChoice = in.nextInt();
            switch (userChoice) {
            case 1:

                //Deposit Money
                boolean inputInvalid = false;

                do {
                    System.out.println("How Much would you like to deposit?");
                    try {
                        in.useDelimiter("\n");
                        amount = in.nextDouble();
                        inputInvalid = false;
                    } catch(InputMismatchException ime) {
                        System.out.println("Invalid input. Try Again");
                        inputInvalid = true;
                    }
                } while (inputInvalid);

                System.out.println("Depositing: " + amount);
                account1.deposit(amount);
                //balance = amount + balance;
                break;
            case 2:
                //Withdraw money
                boolean InvalidInput = false;

                do {
                    System.out.println("How Much would you like to withdraw?");
                    try {
                        in.useDelimiter("\n");
                        amount = in.nextDouble();
                        InvalidInput = false;
                    } catch(InputMismatchException ime) {
                        System.out.println("Invalid input. Try Again");
                        InvalidInput = true;
                    }
                } while (InvalidInput);

                System.out.println("Withdrawing: " + amount);
                account1.withdraw(amount);
                //balance = balance - amount;
                break;
            case 3:
                //check balance
                System.out.println("Checking Balance.");
                account1.getBalance();

                System.out.println(account1.balance);
                break;
            case 0:
                System.out.println("Thanks for Using BankAccount Banking System!");
                quit = true;
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Error: Choice not recognized please choose again.");
                continue;
            }

            if (userChoice ==  0)
                quit = true;
        } while
        (!quit);
    }
}
```

My code otherwise works fine but I can't seem to figure out why it won't stop repeatedly printing my error message for the user. If someone can point out my error for me that would be fantastic.  I did have this same code in another question however they fixed my problem that I had in the last question and were unable to answer the problem that arose here.

Comment: What is the output message ? and which loop?

Comment: Which error message is being output? Have you tried simplifying the code to see if you can narrow down where the problem might be?

Comment: Invalid Input. Try Again keeps repeating, and either 'How much would you like to deposit' or 'How much would you like to withdraw' respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove or comment out the following line from your code :

```
in.useDelimiter("\n");
```

This is causing the the character **"\n"** to be passed to the `amount = in.nextDouble()`, which in turn causes the **InputMismatchException** to be thrown , thus resulting in an infinite loop.

**UPDATE :** Working code and the Sample output for your convinience:

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Bank {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double balance = 0;
        double amount = 0;

        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        int userChoice;
        BankAccount account1 = new BankAccount();
        boolean quit = false;
        {
            do {
                System.out.println("Your Choice: ");
                System.out.println("For Deposit type 1");
                System.out.println("For Withdraw type 2");
                System.out.println("For Check Balance type 3");
                System.out.println("Type 0 to quit");

                System.out.print("User Input :");
                userChoice = in.nextInt();

                switch (userChoice) {
                    case 1:

                    // Deposit Money
                    boolean inputInvalid = false;

                    do {
                        System.out.println("How Much would you like to deposit?");
                        try {
                            // in.useDelimiter("\n");
                            amount = in.nextDouble();
                            inputInvalid = false;
                        } catch (InputMismatchException ime) {
                            System.out.println("Invalid input. Try Again");
                            inputInvalid = true;
                        }
                    } while (inputInvalid);

                   System.out.println("Depositing: " + amount);
                   account1.deposit(amount);
                   // balance = amount + balance;
                    break;

                  case 2:
                  // Withdraw money
                      boolean InvalidInput = false;
                      do {
                          System.out.println("How Much would you like to withdraw?");
                          try {
                              // in.useDelimiter("\n");
                              amount = in.nextDouble();
                              InvalidInput = false;
                          } catch (InputMismatchException ime) {
                              System.out.println("Invalid input. Try Again");
                              InvalidInput = true;
                          }
                      } while (InvalidInput);

                      System.out.println("Withdrawing: " + amount);
                      account1.withdraw(amount);
                      // balance = balance - amount;
                      break;
                   case 3:
            // check balance
            System.out.println("Checking Balance.");
            account1.getBalance();
            System.out.println("Available Balance is : " + account1.getBalance());
            break;
       case 0:
            System.out.println("Thanks for Using BankAccount Banking System!");
            quit = true;
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Error: Choice not recognized please choose again.");
        continue;
    }
    if (userChoice == 0)
        quit = true;
  } while (!quit);
 }
}
}
```

**Sample Output :**

```
Your Choice: 
For Deposit type 1
For Withdraw type 2
For Check Balance type 3
Type 0 to quit
User Input :1
How Much would you like to deposit?
100
Depositing: 100.0
Your Choice: 
For Deposit type 1
For Withdraw type 2
For Check Balance type 3
Type 0 to quit
User Input :25
Error: Choice not recognized please choose again.
Your Choice: 
For Deposit type 1
For Withdraw type 2
For Check Balance type 3
Type 0 to quit
User Input :2
How Much would you like to withdraw?
25
Withdrawing: 25.0
Your Choice: 
For Deposit type 1
For Withdraw type 2
For Check Balance type 3
Type 0 to quit
User Input :3
Checking Balance.
Available Balance is : 75.0
Your Choice: 
For Deposit type 1
For Withdraw type 2
For Check Balance type 3
Type 0 to quit
User Input :0
Thanks for Using BankAccount Banking System!
```

Comment: but when I do that then the next part of my code loops infinitely, it delays the loop one step.

Comment: You need to remove that code from both the places, that is from case1 as well as case2, then it will work fine

Comment: I did and tested it and it is not fine. it still loops infinitely after I input a wrong character. I need it to pause for another user input and then loop

Comment: `do{
  System.out.println("How Much would you like to deposit?");
  try{
   //in.useDelimiter("\n");
   amount = in.nextDouble();
   inputInvalid = false;
  }catch(InputMismatchException ime){
   System.out.println("Invalid input. Try Again\n");
   inputInvalid = true;
  }
  }while (inputInvalid);` Here is the new code that I did with your recommendations. The error is that when this runs it either runs continuously or produces a runtime error.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
            String value = in.nextLine();
            String v="";
            for(int i=0;i<value.length();i++)
                if(value.charAt(i)!='\n')
                    v+=value.charAt(i);

            double amount =-1;
            if(v!=null)
                amount = Double.parseDouble(v);
```

Comment: Nope got this: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
 at Bank.<init>(Bank.java:32)
 at BankRunner.main(BankRunner.java:5)